# How to get and set window popup height and width in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

How to get and set window popup height and width in **Internet Explorer** using JavaScript

In Firefox I am able to set the height and width using outerHeight , outerWidth property of window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an existing window, you can set the size using [`window.resizeTo`](http://www.cybertext.com.au/tips_HTML_window_size.htm) ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536723%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
window.resizeTo(640, 480)
```

Or, you can specify the size when the window's being created using the [`window.open`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) method ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
window.open ("http://stackoverflow.com",
"mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,
width=640,height=480");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('something.html','new_win','width=320,height=240');
```

See also: http://google.com/search?q=popup+window+height+width+ie